# Wordpress Widget on specific author posts

Tags: wordpress, widget, logic, conditional-statements

Using Widget Logic I am trying to get a sidebar widget to only display on any post by a specific author.

I have found the is_author() logic, but this only works with Archive pages not posts. I found the following code which does work for posts:

> global $post; return($post->post_author==2);

however it also displays the widget on the homepage - which I don't want.

So I'm trying to create a combination of this code and !is_front_page() but I can't get the two to work together.

Can anyone combine this correctly for me or have a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this widget logic condition:

```
global $post; return (!is_home() && !is_front_page() && $post->post_author == 2);
```

Widget Logic is a useful plugin, btw.  Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work. it doesn't produce any errors, but it doesn't make the widget appear on posts by the author either. R

Comment: I've installed this plugin and tried it on my test setup.  Please check the updated answer and give it another try.

Comment: hi, nope sorry still isn't working. it does now appear on the /author/xxxx profile page, but still nothing on any post *by* the author which is what I'm after. glad you found the plugin useful!

Comment: Strange, it does work on my host, on both author page and on post pages.  What version of WP do you use, 3.2.1?  Could you also check author id?  Please note, in your case it will work for author with id equal to 2.

Comment: Yes, definitely 3.2.1 and the userid I want to display the plugin for is definitely 2. Odd, thanks for trying though.

Comment: Well, maybe that's your theme.  The other thing you could try is to enable "Use 'wp_reset_query' fix" option in plugin settings.